# Como deshabilitar días anteriores con JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, funciones, date

hola a todos disculpen solicito su ayuda quisiera saber por que mi código no deshabilita la fechas con anterioridad ejemplo hoy 31 supuestamente el cliente no puede pedir una cita el día 30 sin embargo no ser que estoy haciendo mal, les agradecería su ayuda.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Este es el código:

```
 // Funcion de fecha deshabilitada
function deshabilitaFechaAnterior() {
    const inputFecha = document.querySelector('#fecha');
 
    // Obtencion de el año, mes, dia
    const fechaAhora = new Date();
    const year = fechaAhora.getFullYear();
    let mes = fechaAhora.getMonth() + 1;
    let dia = fechaAhora.getDate() + 1;
 
    if(mes < 10){
        mes = `0${mes}`;
    }
 
    if(dia < 10){
        dia = `0${dia}`;
    }
  
    // Formato de la fecha DD-MM-AAAA aqui solo cambie en orden 
    let fechaDeshabilitar = `${dia}-${mes}-${year}`;
 
   inputFecha.min = fechaDeshabilitar;
   
}
```

Comment: para que te acepte el `inputFecha.min`, `fechaDeshabilitar` debe de ser con el formato "año-mes-dia"

Comment: Hola Oscar cambie lo que me comentaste y todavía me sigue aceptando fechas de día anterior

Comment: Otra cosa es que a `fechaAhora.getDate()` no le debes de sumar 1, ya que este si te da el día real, entonces al sumarle 1, en el caso de hoy, el día sería 32, y este ya no es un día válido

Comment: A lo que pasa a fechaAhora.getDate() le agregué el +1 para que no puedan solicitar cita el mismo día si no un día después pero no tome en cuenta ese detalle que me comentas

Answer (score 0):

Para agregarle un día a la fecha actual y solo permita hacer citas para el día siguiente, puedes usar el método setDate(), como muestro a continuación

```
// Funcion de fecha deshabilitada
function deshabilitaFechaAnterior() {
   const inputFecha = document.querySelector('#fecha');

   // Obtencion de el año, mes, dia
   const fechaAhora = new Date();
   const year = fechaAhora.getFullYear();
   let mes = fechaAhora.getMonth() + 1;

   // suma un día a la fecha actual sin inconvenientes, por ejemplo, si el 
   //día actual es 31 de marzo y se le suma un día, la fecha sería 1 de abril
   fechaAhora.setDate(fechaAhora.getDate() + 1);

   let dia = fechaAhora.getDate();

   if(mes < 10){
      mes = `0${mes}`;
   }

   if(dia < 10){
      dia = `0${dia}`;
   }

   // Formato de la fecha minima AAAA-MM-DD 
   let fechaDeshabilitar = `${year}-${mes}-${dia}`;

   inputFecha.min = fechaDeshabilitar;

}
```